# How do I deserialize protobufs without the proto file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have the generated deserialization classes and can generate sample protobufs (byte-buffers). But I do not have the `.proto` files. I  need to stop using these generated classes because they come from a third-party library that may be unsupported and unavailable. How to I parse the byte-buffers myself?

I considered:

- Reverse engineering the binary format by

  - Generating lots of buffers and analyzing them
  - possibly with a
    debugger and the third party classes
  - Reverse-compiling the Java classes to get some (ugly)  source code (but refactoring autogenerated code seems like a bad idea).
- Generating `.proto` files from the class files (not sure if this is possible)
- Generically read protobufs without the `.proto` file and without the autogenerated code, but I am not sure that the buffers have enough embedded metadata for this to be possible.

How can this be done?

Comment: Protobuf is inherently schema-less in terms of the data format. If you don't know what you're expecting, you cannot interpret the data; without knowledge of the layout, it is ambiguous. This knowledge is typically via a .proto and compile-time build tools

Comment: Yes that is true. Here my advantage is that I have the generated files and can run with them in a debugger. And I can generate byte-buffers with many different inputs to reverse-engineer (even the most opaque binary formats can be reverse-engineered, with effort).

I am looking for tips on how to do this.

Comment: you can take guesses, but the same byte sequences can represent a range of different values depending on the original schema. A fixed-32 can be a floating point or an integer; a varint can be signed, unsigned, or zig-zag signed and can be 32-bit or 64-bit; a length-prefixed value could be a packed array, a string, or a sub-message; and so on...

Comment: Not just guesses. I can use the generated de/serializer classes in a debugger. I can generate many different inputs and see what the byte-buffers look like. But I agree that it is difficult, which is why I am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol buffers come with some pretty powerful reflection. Take a look at message descriptors [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor).

Message descriptors contain all the information about the particular message type, so you should be able to figure out all the possible fields from there. You can get a descriptor directly from a proto message using:

`your_proto_message.getDescriptorForType()`

Or using

`ProtoMessageClass.getDescriptor()`

If the .proto file representation is all you're after, you can just call `.toProto()` on the descriptor. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.Descriptor#toProto--).

So, to sum up:

`ProtoMessageClass.getDescriptor().toProto().toString()`

Comment: And toString() gives the proto content:

ProtoMessageClass.getDescriptor().toProto().toString()

Comment: @JoshuaFox Edited my answer to include your comment, thanks!